Fantasy book with a chacter called Robin 9 finger
I'm trying to remember the title of a book I read maybe 30 years ago.  It had a female character who was called Robin the 9 finger.  This Robin character had only 9 fingers because of her bravery.
That's all I remember!

I suspect that you're thinking of the SF (not fantasy) Gaea trilogy by John Varley. The three books are Titan, Wizard, and Demon; Robin is a character from one of the space habs that was entirely female/lesbian and called themselves witches.

Is this Wizard (1980) by John Varley...? It's the second book in the Gaea trilogy.

One of the greatest science fiction epics ever written, John Varley's Titan, Wizard, and Demon comprise a groundbreaking trilogy that will live forever. Human explorers have entered the sprawling mind of Gaea. Now they must fight her will. For she is much too powerful...and definitely insane...

From the Wikipedia page:

Chris Major and Robin the Nine-Fingered are two pilgrims looking for a cure. Chris suffers from psychotic episodes which are often accompanied by paranormal "luck". Robin is a member of a group of latter day witches living in an O'Neill orbital habitat who has a strange epilepsy that only manifests in gravity higher than the Moon's. She claims that she bit off one of her fingers to drive away the fits, though it is later revealed she cut it off.



I remember her.  Had a horror tattoo on her belly to signify that she "could not" bear children.  Also was very short and carried a 1911 pistol loaded with rocket-assisted ammunition.

It has to be this, Wizard was also my best guess. I read it in Italian, where it had a completely different name that mentioned "Titan" in the title for some accursed reasons. The reason the "witches" were short apparently was because the guy who was in charge of sending samples for fecundation hated them to the guts and willingly supplied subpar genetic material iirc...
